# FOSREST Bundle conflict with SensioFrameworkExtraBundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Hi my application is running with `Symfony2.7.15` which contains `new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle()` in `AppKarnel.php` as well.

Now we need to make a Restful API to user webservices. I am trying to install `FOSRESTBundle` for this purpose but I am getting the following error.

```
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 1.8.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.16].
- friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 1.8.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.16].
- friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 1.8.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.16].
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ^1.8 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[1.8.0].
- Installation request for sensio/framework-extra-bundle (locked at v3.0.16, required as ^3.0.2) -> satisfiable by sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.16].
```

Please suggest how to resolved this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to packagist page of [friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle#1.8.0) the version 1.8.0 that you are installing conflicts with `sensio/framework-extra-bundle: >=3.0.13`

You have two choices here:

1. Downgrade sensio/framework-extra-bundle to the first non-conflicting version:

   `$ composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle "3.0.12"`
2. Install more recent version of `friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle` that is compatible with the extra bundle >=3.0.13:

   `$ composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle "2.0.0"`

As far as I can see the newer version is still compatible with Symfony 2.7+ so I would give it a shot.

Comment: Problem 1
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[2.0.0].
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 2.0.0 requires php ^5.5.9|~7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17) overriden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: I have did #1 and Then install the 1.8 version of fosrest bundle its installed now.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of

```
sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

I assume,It's **3.0.16**

And **FOSRestBundle** requires `framework-extra-bundle` to be **3.0.2**, 
Update extra-bundle too. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Update it to **3.0.2**.

Comment: My composer.json already contain this Line:
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2"

Comment: Update extra bundle with `composer` command first and then update/install RESTBundle.

Comment: I have updated the extra buldels using update composer. and after that trying to install Forrest bundle. but getting same error.
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 1.8.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.16].

Comment: I found symfonyextrabundle version still. 3.0.16

Comment: Installation request for sensio/framework-extra-bundle (locked at v3.0.16, required as ^3.0.2) -> satisfiable by sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v3.0.16].

Comment: composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117172/discussion-between-alok-and-sunil-singh-rawat).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and just solved it. 
FOSRestBundle v1.8.0 conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle v3.0.13 or higher. Mentioned here, https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle#1.8.0
Yours is v3.0.16 which is in the conflict range.
Here is the way how you can solve it:
Install FOSRestBundle v2.0.0, which only conflicts with sensio/framework-extra-bundle v3.0.13 or lower versions. So, your v3.0.16 is fine. More details: https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle#2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by running these two commands,

```
$ composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle "3.0.12"

$ composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 1.8
```